# Need help compiling to an APK file for Gamemaker studio

Tags: android, game-maker

Like the title says, I'm having trouble compiling my file into an .apk. It stops the compiling with this error.

Don't know what any of this means. Looked it up, and tried multiple possible solutions and none of them seemed to work

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':com.AnkerDevelopment.NightatChesters'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':com.AnkerDevelopment.NightatChesters:_debugApkCopy'.
  >   Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:29.0.0.
  >   Required by:
  >   project :com.AnkerDevelopment.NightatChesters
  >   Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:29.0.0.
  >   Required by:
  >   project :com.AnkerDevelopment.NightatChesters > com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:16.0.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1
  >   project :com.AnkerDevelopment.NightatChesters > com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.3 > com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Answer (score 0):

The required dependency

```
com.android.support:support-v4:29.0.0
```

could not be downloaded. Are you sure your network connection is working? Do you maybe need a proxy to reach the internet?

Comment: Yeah it's working, otherwise I wouldn't be able to ask this question in the first place. I haven't tried a proxy, though maybe that would help? Sorry I'm new.